# Get display value of CHOICES in python

Tags: django

Within django, I know that if you define a model with choices, you can print the value of the option to a template with the following

Choices and field in models.py

```
NAVBAR_COLOR = (
    (0, "Dark"),
    (1, "Light"),
)

navbarcolor = models.IntegerField(choices=NAVBAR_COLOR, default=1)
```

template

```
{{color.get_navbarcolor_display}}
```

Is there a way to get the display value for the option within python for a given field?

Thanks!

Comment: In python code you can do `color.get_navbarcolor_display()`. Or do you mean something different?

Comment: I think this is it. I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Very odd. That appears to return the int (i.e. either 0 or 1).

Comment: Does `{{color}}` not work? or `{{whateverobject.navbarcolor}}`?

Comment: {{color}} would be an object instance

Answer (score 0):

This returns Dark or Light.

```
        d = dict(NAVBAR_COLOR)
        color = d[int(color.navbarcolor)]
```

Comment: be careful with that one. Are you changing 'color' now from something with navbarcolor property to a string?